# Making a continuous color chart for heatmap using pheatmap

Tags: r, pheatmap

I'm looking to figure out how to use the pheatmap package and to make a continuous color coded heatmap.

I would like to use three colors, red, white and blue to for my map, where white = 0, blue is for negative numbers, and red for positive. I want it such that it would be continuous, rather than anything being 0 = white, and positive being red, but more of a transition from a solid red to lighter fades until white.

I couldnt find it in the documentation, so perhaps it is my lack of understanding on how to get it to work.

Here is my code currently.

```
pheatmap(heatmap_matrix,
  cluster_rows = T,
  cluster_cols = T,
  color = c("blue", "white", "red"),
  angle_col = 90)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just supply a long vector of transitioning colours using `colorRampPalette`:

```r
set.seed(1)
heatmap_matrix <- matrix(rnorm(400), nrow = 20)

pheatmap(heatmap_matrix,
  cluster_rows = T,
  cluster_cols = T,
  color = colorRampPalette(c("blue", "white", "red"))(100),
  angle_col = 90)
```

[image]

Comment: Thats a good idea! Thank you! Unfortunately, I get this error: Error in seq.default(min(x, na.rm = T), max(x, na.rm = T), length.out = n + : attempt to apply non-function

Any thoughts on how to approach this?

Comment: @SpiderK do you get the error if you cut and paste my code exactly?